# WebAPI HTTPPost Data Validation

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-post

I'm using WebAPI Datacontrollers in an ASP.NET MVC application and wondering what is the best practice for putting server side valiation?

1) Do in the API controller itself?
2) Do just before the data insert (source level)?

And how should the response go to the client?

Answer (score 1):

In web api controller you can validate your model like below code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace MyApi.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        [Range(0, 999)]
        public double Weight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and your post action will be like this:

```
using MyApi.Models;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
namespace MyApi.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Do something with the product (not shown).

                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try this, it will work for you.
For more details refer this link: [Model Validation in Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api)